# Converting Row to Column vector in python using python and shape should result (n,1) to (1,n)?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, vector

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])

arr1 = np.transpose(arr)

print(arr1.shape,arr.shape)
```

**output**:(5,) (5,)

What should i change to get output as (1,5) (5,1) after transpose?

Comment: `arr` is (5,) not (1,5).  In numpy there's a difference, especially when transposing existing axes.

Answer (score 1):

you must expand your dimensions first:

```py
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])

arr_expanded = np.expand_dims(arr,axis=0)

arr_transposed = arr_expanded.T
```

```py
print(arr_expanded.shape,arr_transposed.shape)
>>> (1, 5) (5, 1)
```